# Best units to responsive layout

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am starting a new responsive application, and i was thinking in use percentage to ( Font / Width / Height / Margin / Padding )... will my application get heavy ??

what is the best unit to use for:

- Font
- Width
- Height
- Margin/Padding

Comment: Too subjective...completely depends..

Comment: Check out these related questions: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+best+units+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=css+best+units+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best" is more of a subjective thing but here is a pretty good article in defense of using `em`s.

http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

and if it seems tedious to do all the conversions, I've found this tool plenty helpful

http://pxtoem.com/

Answer (score 0):

For text I'm heavily in favor of using em. For width, use percentages, and height use auto or pixel.

To calculate percentages, take the pixel width divided by the target width multiplied by 100. For example:

You have a 1024px width container and a div within the container of 400px. To figure the width of the 400px container in percentages you divide 400 / 1024 * 100 = 39.0625% width.

The formula for figuring ems is desired web font size divided by standard web font size. For example:

you want 22px font, so: 22 / 16 = 1.375em.

Using percentage and em doesn't make your app any heavier than calling standard pixels does.

for padding you use the same formula as for width, but the target is the container width you are applying padding to, not it's parent width.

Don't forget to set max-width: 100%; on the topmost container element (or some smaller percentage if you want gutters even on smaller screens).